# How to use || inside a lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, lambda

I filter out what documents a user can see in the webapi Get call. The CompanyName in the Document object must match the users assigned CompanyName(s). So if a user as been assigned with CompanyName1 and CompanyName2 they can only return the Documents that match them.

```
public List<Document> GetDocuments()
    {
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {

            return context.Documents
                .Where(j => j.CompanyName == user.CompanyName1) || (j => j.CompanyName == user.CompanyName2) || (j => j.CompanyName == user.CompanyName2)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

This obvisouly does not work but it is what I need it to do.

> Error 1 Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' and 'lambda expression'
>
> Error 2 Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'lambda expression'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

only use `y =>` once

```
       return context.Documents
            .Where(j => j.CompanyName == user.CompanyName1 ||
                        j.CompanyName == user.CompanyName2 ||  
                        j.CompanyName == user.CompanyName2)
            .ToList();
```